# Python recursion with dicts

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, tree

I beg your help in order to solve a problem where I'm losing my mind since 3 days.

It's pretty hard to explain but I'm trying to transform this dict:

```
{
    'contrats': [
        {
            'code': '1234567890',
            'produits': [
                {
                    'code': 'MAGENTA',
                },
                {
                    'code': 'EMERAUDE',
                },
            ],
            'familles': [
                {
                    'code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
                    'personnes': [
                        {
                            'code': 'MR_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Monsieur',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
                            'role_famille': 'A',
                            'roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'MME_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Madame',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
                            'role_famille': 'C',
                            'roles_contrat': ['C'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'E1_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Enfant 1',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
                            'role_famille': 'E',
                            'roles_contrat': ['E'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'E2_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Enfant 2',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
                            'role_famille': 'E',
                            'roles_contrat': ['E'],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

http://dpaste.com/2QFMSYQ

Into this dict:

```
[
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'MAGENTA',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
    'personne_role_famille': 'A',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
    'personne_role_famille': 'A',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'MAGENTA',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Madame',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
    'personne_role_famille': 'C',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Madame',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
    'personne_role_famille': 'C',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'MAGENTA',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
    'personne_role_famille': 'E',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
    'personne_role_famille': 'E',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'MAGENTA',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
    'personne_role_famille': 'E',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
},
{
    'contrat_code': '1234567890',
    'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE',
    'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
    'personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
    'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
    'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
    'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
    'personne_role_famille': 'E',
    'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
},
]
```

http://dpaste.com/3S5K4TF

As you see, I need to merge all the keys/values (context) of the dict on one level only.

I have a beginning of algorithm but it returns only 4 contexts instead of 8 expected.

```
def creer_contextes(contexte, sections, ctx=None, done=None):
   resultats = []
   ctx_local = (ctx or {}).copy()
   vues = (done or set()).copy()
   sections_ = set(aplatir(sections))
   for section in sections_ - vues:
      for element in contexte.get(section, []):
         copie = element.copy()
         normalisation = normaliser(copie, section[:-1], *sections_)
         ctx_local.update(normalisation)
         vues.add(section)
         if vues == sections_:
             resultats += [ctx_local.copy()]
         if any(s in element.keys() for s in sections_):
             resultats += creer_contextes(copie, sections, ctx=ctx_local, done=vues)
   return resultats


def aplatir(ilist):
    return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else aplatir(x) for x in ilist), [])


def normaliser(idict, clef, *excludes):
    return {'{}_{}'.format(clef, key): value for key, value in idict.items() if key not in excludes}
```

Thank you very much for any help provided!

Comment: Why the desire to do this recursively? The keys cannot be simply hardcoded here? Your data structure is not that suited for recursive processing, you have essentially a product of 4 lists here, but they are partially nested, partially adjacent.

Comment: And for a proper generic approach you'd have to extend your key prefixes to include the hierarchy; what if there is a second `contrats` nested structure deeper within the structure?

Comment: And why is `roles_contrat` excluded here? I'd expect more multiplication for each separate value in those lists here.

Comment: The dict can totally change between each execution, so I can't know the keys before the execution.

Comment: I can add the hierarchy to the key prefixes but how it can help me ? And `roles_contrat` is not excluded in my example.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that because the values *in* the list are not dictionaries, you can detect that those are not to be used to multiply your outputs.

Comment: In fact, I'm sure I don't retrieve the "section" twice in my dict. But if it happens, we could have a bad time.

Comment: Yes, values in list could be both dicts and primitives. Impossible to know precisely if it's a section or an attribute or my section.

Comment: If you are getting just the 4 results, you are missing the `produits` multiplication, because it is adjacent to the `familles` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to handle adjacent lists here, recursing into the structure to extend the result dictionary as we go. By using `itertools.product()` you don't have to recurse on the same 'level' of nesting just because there are multiple nested structures in a given level:

```
from itertools import product

def recursive_flatten(d, prefix=''):
    result = {}
    nested = {}

    # extract just the 'flat' keys for the result
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        result_key = (prefix + '_' + key.rstrip('s')).lstrip('_')
        if isinstance(value, list) and value and isinstance(value[0], dict):
            # nested dictionaries are treated recursively
            nested[result_key] = value
            continue
        result[result_key] = value

    # no nested keys? We are done here
    if not nested:
        yield result
        return

    # produce a new copy for each combination of nested structures
    for nested_combos in product(*nested.values()):
        results = [result]
        for nested_key, nested_value in zip(nested, nested_combos):
            # multiply results with nested results
            results = [
                dict(r, **rec_result)
                for rec_result in recursive_flatten(nested_value, nested_key)
                for r in results]
        for result in results:
            yield result
```

I am producing longer keys here; prefixing nested structures with the key for the parent, recursively. So everything is prefixed with `contrat_`, then data from the `familles` list is prefixed with `contrat_famille_`, etc. If you don't want this, then use `nested[key.rstrip('s')] = value` instead of `nested[result_key] = value` in the first loop in the function.

However, I feel that not prefixing the keys can lead to producing conflicting keys (if there are multiple `contrat` keys with nested structures at different levels of the tree, for example).

This does assume that your data structure is at least *consistent*; if the first element of a list is a dictionary, then *all* elements in that list are dictionaries.

This produces the expected output (albeit with longer keys) for your sample:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(recursive_flatten(sample)))
[{'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'A',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Madame',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'C',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'A',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Madame',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'C',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'contrat_famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
  'contrat_famille_personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'contrat_famille_personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
  'contrat_famille_personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'contrat_famille_personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'contrat_produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'}]
```

Comment: Woh. Impressive. I have to understand how it works now. My aim is to get only two levels of key for the result dict, i.e. `contrat_code` or `personne_role_famille` and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same also on "dicts of dicts"? (not only lists of dicts)

Comment: @MarcDebureaux: with nested dictionaries there is no multiplication; the recursion becomes a lot simpler then. You could then just use `result.update()` to update the one result dictionary with the nested call result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def is_list_dict(l):
    return isinstance(l, list) and len(l) and isinstance(l[0], dict)

def fix_list(name, lst, extra):
    """Given a list of dictionaries, generate a list of flattened dictionaries"""
    for d in lst:
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for d1 in fix_dict(name, d):
                d2 = d1.copy()
                d2.update(extra)
                yield d2
        else:
            yield d

def fix_dict(name, d):
    """
    Given a name and dictionary, returns a list of dictionaries.
    """
    name = name.rstrip('s')
    extra = [{ '{}_{}'.format(name, k):v for k,v in d.items() if not is_list_dict(v) }]

    res = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if is_list_dict(v):
            extra2 = []
            for x in extra:
                extra2.extend(fix_list(k, v, x))
            extra = extra2
    return extra

def recursive_flatten(d):
    return list(fix_list('', [d], {}))

from pprint import pprint
data = {
    'contrats': [
        {
            'code': '1234567890',
            'produits': [
                {
                    'code': 'MAGENTA',
                },
                {
                    'code': 'EMERAUDE',
                },
            ],
            'familles': [
                {
                    'code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
                    'personnes': [
                        {
                            'code': 'MR_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Monsieur',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
                            'role_famille': 'A',
                            'roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'MME_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Madame',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
                            'role_famille': 'C',
                            'roles_contrat': ['C'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'E1_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Enfant 1',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
                            'role_famille': 'E',
                            'roles_contrat': ['E'],
                        },
                        {
                            'code': 'E2_KLEIN',
                            'nom': 'KLEIN',
                            'prenom': 'Enfant 2',
                            'date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
                            'role_famille': 'E',
                            'roles_contrat': ['E'],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
pprint(recursive_flatten(data))
```

Output matches what is required, even the order of the output is the same though I assume that doesn't actually matter:

```
[{'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
  'personne_role_famille': 'A',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
  'produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'MR_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1973',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Monsieur',
  'personne_role_famille': 'A',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['A', 'S', 'P'],
  'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Madame',
  'personne_role_famille': 'C',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
  'produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'MME_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1976',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Madame',
  'personne_role_famille': 'C',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['C'],
  'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
  'personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'E1_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/1998',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 1',
  'personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
  'personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'produit_code': 'MAGENTA'},
 {'contrat_code': '1234567890',
  'famille_code': 'FAMILLE_KLEIN',
  'personne_code': 'E2_KLEIN',
  'personne_date_naissance': '01/01/2001',
  'personne_nom': 'KLEIN',
  'personne_prenom': 'Enfant 2',
  'personne_role_famille': 'E',
  'personne_roles_contrat': ['E'],
  'produit_code': 'EMERAUDE'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of @martijn-pieters with nested dictionaries. Am I right?

```
def recursive_flatten(idict, prefix='', long_keys=False, separator='_'):
    """
    Met à plat un dictionnaire (avec listes et dictionnaires imbriqués) en renommant les clés
    :param idict: Dictionnaire à mettre à plat
    :param prefix: Préfixe des clés (utile pendant la récursion)
    :param long_keys: Utilise des clés longues (avec l'historique de la hiérarchie)
    :param separator: Séparateur entre les sections et les clés
    :return: (Générateur) Combinaison du dictionnaire
    """
    result = {}
    nested = {}
    dicts = []

    # Récupère les clés mises à plat
    for key, value in idict.items():
        result_key = (prefix + separator + key.rstrip('s')).lstrip(separator)
        if isinstance(value, list) and value and isinstance(value[0], dict):
            # Les dictionnaire imbriqués dans des listes sont à traiter récursivement
            nested[result_key if long_keys else key.rstrip('s')] = value
            continue
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            # Les dictionnaires imbriqués dans des dictionnaires sont récupérés immédiatement par récursivité
            dicts += list(recursive_flatten(value, result_key, long_keys, separator))
            continue
        result[result_key] = value

    # Retourne le résultat s'il n'y a pas de clés imbriquées
    if not nested:
        # Ajoute les dictionnaires imbriqués
        for d in dicts:
            result.update(d)
        yield result
        return

    # Crée les différentes combinaisons des structures imbriquées
    for nested_combos in product(*nested.values()):
        results = [result]
        for nested_key, nested_value in zip(nested, nested_combos):
            # Fusionne les données imbriquées avec les résultats
            if isinstance(nested_value, dict):
                results = [
                    dict(r, **rec_result)
                    for rec_result in recursive_flatten(nested_value, nested_key, long_keys, separator)
                    for r in results
                ]
        for result in results:
            # Ajoute les dictionnaires imbriqués
            for d in dicts:
                result.update(d)
            yield result

# Récupère les clés mises à plat
for key, value in idict.items():
    result_key = (prefix + separator + key.rstrip('s')).lstrip(separator)
    if isinstance(value, list) and value and isinstance(value[0], dict):
        # Les dictionnaire imbriqués dans des listes sont à traiter récursivement
        nested[result_key if long_keys else key.rstrip('s')] = value
        continue
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        # Les dictionnaires imbriqués dans des dictionnaires sont récupérés immédiatement par récursivité
        dicts += list(recursive_flatten(value, result_key, long_keys, separator))
        continue
    result[result_key] = value

# Retourne le résultat s'il n'y a pas de clés imbriquées
if not nested:
    # Ajoute les dictionnaires imbriqués
    for d in dicts:
        result.update(d)
    yield result
    return

# Crée les différentes combinaisons des structures imbriquées
for nested_combos in product(*nested.values()):
    results = [result]
    for nested_key, nested_value in zip(nested, nested_combos):
        # Fusionne les données imbriquées avec les résultats
        if isinstance(nested_value, dict):
            results = [
                dict(r, **rec_result)
                for rec_result in recursive_flatten(nested_value, nested_key, long_keys, separator)
                for r in results
            ]
    for result in results:
        # Ajoute les dictionnaires imbriqués
        for d in dicts:
            result.update(d)
        yield result
```